# How much does this mess up a browser?

Tags: jquery

A friend of mine recently shared this with me:

```
$("*").append($("*")); // watch your browser eat itself
```

What exactly does this jQuery try to do? Does it result in an infinite loop, or does it just mangle the DOM by iteratively appending every element to every other element? I know that appending an element to a different one essentially moves it there from its current parent. But what would happen when it tries to append an element to itself? Does it simply error out and die, or skip that step and move on?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3 ` here.

Comment: Modify the $ function in jquery to write some debugging info to the console and watch your answer unfold before your eyes.

Comment: `Uncaught exception: DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR` in Opera and IE 9. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both Chrome and FFX (didn't test in IE because I'm scared) I get a Hierarchy Request Error which happens when you try to append a node to itself or append to a null node, or a bunch of other similar reasons.

This means that logically it actually does go through the DOM tree and attempt to append others first .. the selector selects the same node twice and tries to append it to itself, which results in the error.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it it errors out (and does nothing) because you are trying to append absolutely everything, `html / head / script / body` tags. I'm assuming that is because adding some of these tags inside of specific tags triggers an error. (ie: adding all those `<html/head/etc>` tags inside of a `<script>` tag.)

Answer (score 0):

`*` is the CSS selector for all tags.  So basically "append all tags to all tags".